# ListView CAB Checked item coloring

Tags: android, android-listview, contextual-action-bar

I'm at a loss because I feel like android should be taking care of this default selection behavior...

I'm using actionbarsherlock with a listview and have a contextual action bar appearing after an item long click.  I want the items to appear highlighted after the long click but instead they just do the initial flashed darkening of blue and then they revert to their default color.  Am I missing something?

```
    mHabitListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mHabitListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mHabitListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                if (mHabitListView.isItemChecked(position)){
                    mHabitListView.setItemChecked(position, false);


                } else {
                    mHabitListView.setItemChecked(position, true);

                }

                if (mHabitListView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {

                    if (mMode == null) {
                        mMode = startActionMode(new ModeCallback());
                    } else {
                        mMode.setTitle(mHabitListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " " + getString(R.string.cab_selected_count));

                    }
                } else {
                    if (mMode != null) {
                        mMode.finish();

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

    });






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_add_new_habit:
            Habit h = new Habit("Floss", "GOOD", "", "");

            mDbHelper.createHabitEntry(h);
            mDbHelper.close();

            Cursor cursor =  mDbHelper.getAllEntries();
            mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);

            break;
    }
    return true;
}



 private final class ModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Create the menu from the xml file
            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            mode.setTitle(mHabitListView.getCheckedItemCount() + " " + getString(R.string.cab_selected_count));
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Here, you can checked selected items to adapt available actions
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Destroying action mode, let's unselect all items
            for (int i = 0; i < mHabitListView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                mHabitListView.setItemChecked(i, false);

            if (mode == mMode) {
                mMode = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            long[] selected = mHabitListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            if (selected.length > 0) {
                for (long id: selected) {
                    // Do something with the selected item
                }
            }
            mode.finish();
            return true;


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Background of your **Listitem** as  `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`

if you still face any issue then try removing the `listSelector` attribute from your `ListView` xml

Answer (score -1):

you can use *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2*

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2,
    null,
    new String[] { Favorite.BUS_NAME, Favorite.STATION_NAME },
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, }, 0);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

[image]

Comment: I am not going to limit myself to that layout, I have a custom listview row layout that I am using